# Angular 2.1 append component dynamicly inside directive

Tags: angular, typescript

I am a beginner in the angular 2.1. I Want to decorate some elements for the automatical translation and I am going to use a directive, it have to look like:

```
<span customDirectiveTranslation="translateble">{{translateble}}</span>
```

or just

```
<span customDirectiveTranslation>{{translateble}}</span>
```

I can use the Renderer inside directive class (createElement), but by this way I can append only simple elements like span.

how can I render component inside another component by custom directive?
Thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
constructor(
    private target:ViewContainerRef, 
    private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver, 
    private compiler: Compiler) {}

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.createComponent();
}

createComponent() {
    let factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(MyDynamicComponent);
    this.cmpRef = this.target.createComponent(factory)
}
```

See also [Angular 2 dynamic tabs with user-click chosen components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468)

Comment: but in the link some code of my directive, I have got an exception: EXCEPTION: Error in ./TagComponent class TagComponent - inline template:0:0 caused by: No component factory found for TestComponentComponent

Comment: You need to add `TestComponentComponent` to `entryComponents` in `@NgModule()` so that a factory is created.

Comment: O_O I cannot belive

Comment: By this way the new component will be created after (or before) the directive-marked component, can i put the new component inside?

Comment: No, only as sibling. You need a `ViewContainerRef` of an element inside the element, then you can add it inside.

Comment: Thanx for your response, can i get it inside the Directive's class? basicly I have to have the common directive for all tags which can contain tags...

Comment: I don't get what you mean by "common directive for all tags". You can try `@ContentChild(xxx, {ViewContainerRef})` in the directive to get a `ViewContainerRef` where `xxx` is a template variable of the element in the component or the type of a component or directive on the element that should work as target. I have seen it mentioned but I haven't tried if this actually works.

Comment: I mean, that I want to be able to apply my directive to all tags, for example:
<span translatable="eng">{{text}}</span> will be <span>text<div>translation</div></span>
or 
<p translatable="eng, ger">markupble text</p> will be
<p>markupble text<div>english translation</div><div>german translation</div></p>

Comment: Then you need a selector in the directive that matches all these elements. You can use `selector: '[translatable]'`. Have you considered using a pipe instead of a directive?

Comment: Please add full code. where is private compiler: Compiler used? where you defined this.cmpRef?